Is "$x_n>y_n \text{ holds for arbitrarily large } n \Leftrightarrow \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} >1$" true?
Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq (0,\infty)$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq (0,\infty)$ be some positive (possibly unbounded) sequences. I am trying to "cleanly" and "tightly" characterize the necessary and sufficient conditions under which $x_{n}>y_{n}$ holds for arbitrarily large $n$. Is the following statement true?
$$x_n>y_n \text{ holds for arbitrarily large } n \Leftrightarrow \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} >1.$$
My proof is found below. Please let me know if it is correct. If it is incorrect, please let me know what statement should be to the right of "$\Leftrightarrow$" in the above statement. Thank you very much
$\ $

My proof: First I prove the "$\Rightarrow$" part, via proof by contrapositive. Suppose that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n} = \lim\limits_{n'\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n\geq n'}\frac{x_n}{y_n} \leq 1$. This implies that $\exists n'\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\sup_{n\geq n'} \frac{x_n}{y_n} \leq 1$. It then follows that $x_{n}/y_{n}\leq 1$ $\forall n\geq n'$, which is equivalent to saying that $x_n \leq y_n$ holds $\forall n\geq n'$. Therefore $x_n>y_n$ fails to hold for arbitrarily large $n$.
Now I prove the "$\Leftarrow$" part. Suppose that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n} = \lim\limits_{n'\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n\geq n'}\frac{x_n}{y_n} = \sigma$ for some $\sigma>1$. I now proceed via proof by contradiction. Suppose that $\exists m\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n'\geq m$, $\frac{x_{n'}}{y_{n'}}\leq 1$ holds. (This is the negation of "$x_n>y_n$ holds for arbitrarily large $n$.") It then follows that $\sup_{n\geq n'}\frac{x_{n'}}{y_{n'}}\leq 1$ holds $\forall n'\geq m$, since the supremum is the smallest upper bound. This yields a contradiction to the supposition that $\lim\limits_{n'\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n\geq n'}\frac{x_n}{y_n} = \sigma$. Therefore, such an $m$ cannot exist, so $x_n>y_n$ must hold for arbitrarily large $n$. $\ \blacksquare$

The statement is not true. Look at fx. the sequences n+1 and n. As for your proof for the the left to right implication, when you write "This implies that there exists n s.t. ..." is wrong, again, see the example as to why.

I see. Does this mean that the "only if" part has to be "$\geq 1$" rather than "$>1$," while if "if" part can have "$>1$?"
Could you provide guidance on constructing the correct statement for "$x_n>y_n$ holds for arbitrarily large $n$ if and only if _____?"
Thank you for your response.

Yes, that would fix it.

Thank you, Richard. It's a shame that the "if" and "only if" parts have to be different.

Yeah, that's the tricky thing about limits. Strict inequalities rarely hold in the limit :). You could change the inequalities to be non-strict on both sides, and the statement would then be correct.

The "if" direction is wrong also. Take $x_n = 2\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ y_n = 1$ if $n$ odd; $y_n = 3$ if $n$ even. The proposition in the question could be rectified by changing $\limsup$ to $\liminf.$

The implication $\Rightarrow$ is wrong. This can be seen by looking at the sequences given by $x_n = 1 + \frac 1n$ and $y_n = 1$. Then $x_n > y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbf N$, but $\limsup_n \frac{x_n}{y_n} = \lim_n (1 + \frac 1n) = 1$.
The issue with your proof is the following: You claim that the limit of $\sup_{n' \geq n} \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ being greater or equal $1$ implies infinitely many of these suprema being greater or equal to $1$. This is not true, not even one of the suprema has to be $\geq 1$. A convergent sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n > b$ has a limit $\geq b$, but not necessarily $> b$.
